# Cocoa Touch UITableView Alphabetical '#' Match All Unmatched

Tags: iphone, cocoa-touch, ipad

I have a UITableView containing names that I would like to group (and sort) by the first letter (similar to the Address Book application). I am currently able to match any section ('A'-'Z') using:

```
// Sections is an array of strings "{search}" and "A" to "Z" and "#".
NSString *pattern = [self.sections objectAtIndex:section];
NSPredicate *predicate = nil;

// Ignore search pattern.
if ([pattern isEqualToString:@"{search}"]) return nil;

// Non-Alpha and Non-Diacritic-Alpha (?).
if ([pattern isEqualToString:@"#"]);

// Default case (use case and diacritic insensitivity).
if (!predicate) predicate = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"name beginswith[cd] %@", pattern];

// Return filtered results.
return [self.friends filteredArrayUsingPredicate:predicate];
```

However, matching for the '#' eludes me. I tried constructing a REGEX match using:

```
[NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"name matches '[^a-zA-Z].*'"];
```

But this fails for diacritic-alpha (duplicate rows appear). Any ideas would be greatly appreciated! Thanks.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I typically use `UILocalizedIndexedCollation` and a custom `NSArray` category to deal with this. I also have a wrapper (decorator) for UILocalizedIndexedCollation that will include the search symbol and handle the offsets for this for you.

The implementation of my `NSArray` category is here: http://gist.github.com/375409

So, given an array of objects `objects` with a `name` property, I would create an indexed array like so:

```
UILocalizedIndexedCollation *collation = [UILocalizedIndexedCollation currentCollation];
NSArray *indexedObjects = [objects indexUsingCollation:collation withSelector:@selector(name)]; // returns an array of arrays
```

Its important to note that `UILocalizedIndexedCollation` already deals with the logic of indexing and grouping your objects in a localized manner, so there is no need to reinvent the wheel here.

My collation decorator that deals with the search icon can be found in [this github gist](http://gist.github.com/305676).

A more detailed tutorial on using it can be found [on my blog](http://lukeredpath.co.uk/blog/using-uilocalizedindexedcollation-with-searchable-table-views.html).

In this case, you would simply pass in an instance of my collation wrapper instead of UILocalizedIndexedCollation in the example above.

Comment: Thanks for the quick reply Luke! I am just taking a look through everything now and doing fixes to see if it works! Cheers.